# Button's background don't appear on AVD

Tags: android

I just started learning about Android Development and i created an example project. It just a true of false game. Both in AVD and phone only appear the button texts.But in graphical layout of activity_main.xml buttons previewed normally.Can anyone can help me configure that??

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="24dp"
/>


<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal" 
     android:weightSum="4"
>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/true_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/true_button" />

<Button
   android:id="@+id/false_button"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/false_button" />



 </LinearLayout>


<Button
   android:id="@+id/next_button"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/next_button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please post your layout file

Comment: Why are use weightsum ? If it's not need then remove it and check again layout.

Comment: I forgotted to delete weightsum. Do you mean something specifing to look for in layout?